# Calling 'git config' from a script - variable expansion

Tags: bash, git, git-config

I am using the following command to configure the git smudge filter:

```
git config filter.ptc.clean "foo bar baz"
git config filter.ptc.smudge "foo bar baz"
```

It works.

Now, I want to put this into a 'configure_filters.sh' script, my naive approach looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="\"foo bar baz\""
git config filter.ptc.clean $COMMAND
git config filter.ptc.smudge $COMMAND
```

Running 'configure_filters.sh' does not work. git config complains about the arguments.

`bash -x configure_filters.sh` returns:

> ```
> + COMMAND='"foo bar baz"'
> + git config filter.ptc.smudge '"foo' bar 'baz"'
> usage: git config [<options>]
> ...
> ```

It seems like the `COMMAND` variable isn't expanded as I would expect it. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By surrounding your variable with double quotes instead, it becomes exactly as you executed it manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="foo bar baz"
git config filter.ptc.clean "$COMMAND"
git config filter.ptc.smudge "$COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to pass parameters as `"foo bar baz"` with `"` included in values then use following:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="\"foo bar baz\""
git config filter.ptc.clean "$COMMAND"
git config filter.ptc.smudge "$COMMAND"
```

In case you want to pass `foo bar baz` only and those`"` were there since you thought you ran them from command line and they needed then I believe only wrapping up `"$COMMAND"` should work as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="foo bar baz"
git config filter.ptc.clean "$COMMAND"
git config filter.ptc.smudge "$COMMAND"
```